# How do I solve for the derivative using quotient rule

Tags: functions, derivatives

How do I solve for $f'(x)$ when $f(x)=\frac{-e^x\sin x}{\cos x}$? Please show me the steps you took, I myself have spent about an hour on this :(

Comment: What is the central operation or in other words what would be the last operation you would do when calculating this expression? Start by deriving this operation.

Comment: When I applied the rule I ended up with:                                                     (-e^x)(cosx)*(cosx)-(-sinx)*((-e^x)sinx)/(cosx)^2

Answer (score 3):

I would calculate it as a product, since it is $\;-\mathrm e^x\tan x$:
$$(-\mathrm e^x\tan x)'=-\bigl((\mathrm e^x)'\tan x+\mathrm e^x(\tan x)'\bigr)=-\mathrm e^x(\tan^2x+\tan x+1).$$

Comment: I asked for help with the quotient rule, but this works quite well. Thank you.

Comment: I mentioned it because it's simpler than using the quotient rule. Naturally, if you're really asked to use the quotient rule, my answer is irrelevant, but it was not fully clear to me  from your post.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**. One may apply
$$
\left( \frac{f}{g}\right)'=\frac{f'g-fg'}{g^2} \tag1
$$ with
$$
f(x)=-e^x \sin x,\quad g(x)=\cos x.
$$
Find $f'(x),\, g'(x)$ then use $(1)$.

Comment: I'll try that again

Comment: I got ((-e^x)* (cos^2x+sin^x))/(cos^2x) which is (-e^x)/cos^2x

Comment: I checked with wolfram alpha, and i subbed in 2.5, my answer is wrong. Here is what I did when I applied the quotient rule:                                    ((-e^x)(cosx)*(cosx)-(-sinx)*((-e^x)sinx)/(cosx)^2